# How to create cluster for multiple processes?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a 31 CPU machine available for parallel computations. I would like to create a single 31-node cluster which would then serve for parallel computations to several different R processes. How can this be done?

I am currently using `makeCluster` in a way like this:

```
cl <- makeCluster(5)
registerDoParallel(cl)
```

but this will only serve the current R process. How can I connect to a cluster created in different R process?

PS: The reason why I want multiple processes to access one cluster is that I want to be constantly adding new sets of computations which will be waiting in the queue for the running processes to finish. I hope it will work this way? I have used `doRedis` for this in the past, but there were some problems and I would like to use a simple cluster for the purpose.

Comment: You can't because PSOCK clusters communicate with R connections and those cannot be transferred to another R session.

Comment: @HenrikB thanks. You probably meant "you cant with `makeCluster()`, right? But I am also open to solution using different parallel backends, different functions/packages...

Comment: Yes, `parallel::makeCluster()` creates PSOCK clusters. It might be that there are other types of workers that could achieve what you want but I don't know.  Redis is certainly something I would invest time looking for this.  It sounds like you're trying implement some type of work/job queue.  Maybe it's just easier, and certainly more robust, to look into real job schedulers such as Slurm.  The future.batchtools backend for futures supports that.